# Error when trying to start server after upgrading to Rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I've just upgraded to Rails 3, using the instructions from [this railscast](http://railscasts.com/episodes/225-upgrading-to-rails-3-part-1). When I try to start the server, this is what happens:

```
$ rails s
script/rails:6:in `require': no such file to load -- rails/commands (LoadError)
    from script/rails:6:in `<main>'
```

I can't find this exact error using Google. Anyone know what is causing this? Thanks for reading

EDIT:

Here's the console output:

```
$ rvm 1.9.2
$ rails -v
Rails 3.0.1
$ ruby -v
ruby 1.9.2p0 (2010-08-18 revision 29036) [x86_64-darwin10.4.0]
$ rails new . -d sqlite3
(all the overwrite checking stuff happens here)
$ bundle install
...
Your bundle is complete! It was installed into /Users/ben/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0
$ rails s
script/rails:6:in `require': no such file to load -- rails/commands (LoadError)
    from script/rails:6:in `<main>'
$ rvm list
rvm rubies
=> ruby-1.9.2-p0 [ x86_64 ]
$ ruby -v
ruby 1.9.2p0 (2010-08-18 revision 29036) [x86_64-darwin10.4.0]
$ rails -v
script/rails:6:in `require': no such file to load -- rails/commands (LoadError)
    from script/rails:6:in `<main>'
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you actually installed the rails 3.0.x gem? Maybe you missed this step :).

It looks like your `script/rails` script cannot find the included file from rails gem. You need to install all needed gems separately for **each** version of Ruby you're using (e.g. 1.8.7 and 1.9.2).

Comment: thanks for your answer. That does seem to be the problem, although I can't work out how it happened. I've pasted some console output into the original question. Thanks again.

Comment: How does your `Gemfile.lock` look like?

Comment: didn't realize I still had Rails 2 specified in the Gemfile. Works now, thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can just reinstall your rubygem, or update it.

Rubygem versions should fit to your Ruby versions. For every Ruby version you installed separated Gems needed.

May I ask did you use any 'sudo' with RVM installations? Better to avoid, see here:
http://rvm.beginrescueend.com/rubies/rubygems/

Can you list here please your "gem list" after switched to default Ruby version you want to use? Also "rvm list" "ruby -v" "gem -v" and your OS please.

Also wise to write to forum at the section you downloaded Railscasts' video, because maybe others will have the same problem.