# Can't start rails server after 3.0.1 upgrade

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

Followed instructions on [Railscast](http://railscasts.com/episodes/225-upgrading-to-rails-3-part-1) but can't get server to start. It states the following error:

```
$ rails s 
script/rails:6:in `require': no such file to load -- rails/commands (LoadError)`
from script/rails:6:in `<main>'
```

Saw the answer on [this related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4042471/error-when-trying-to-start-server-after-upgrading-to-rails-3) but my Gemfile has no reference to any rails 2.x version and in the "bundle install" results i get this in the results: "Using rails (3.0.1)"

EDIT: (adding Gemfile.lock details)

```
GEM
  remote: http://rubygems.org/
  specs:
    abstract (1.0.0)
    actionmailer (3.0.1)
      actionpack (= 3.0.1)
      mail (~> 2.2.5)
    actionpack (3.0.1)
      activemodel (= 3.0.1)
      activesupport (= 3.0.1)
      builder (~> 2.1.2)
      erubis (~> 2.6.6)
      i18n (~> 0.4.1)
      rack (~> 1.2.1)
      rack-mount (~> 0.6.12)
      rack-test (~> 0.5.4)
      tzinfo (~> 0.3.23)
    activemodel (3.0.1)
      activesupport (= 3.0.1)
      builder (~> 2.1.2)
      i18n (~> 0.4.1)
    activerecord (3.0.1)
      activemodel (= 3.0.1)
      activesupport (= 3.0.1)
      arel (~> 1.0.0)
      tzinfo (~> 0.3.23)
    activeresource (3.0.1)
      activemodel (= 3.0.1)
      activesupport (= 3.0.1)
    activesupport (3.0.1)
    arel (1.0.1)
      activesupport (~> 3.0.0)
    builder (2.1.2)
    calendar_date_select (1.16.1)
    erubis (2.6.6)
      abstract (>= 1.0.0)
    googlecharts (1.6.0)
    i18n (0.4.2)
    mail (2.2.9)
      activesupport (>= 2.3.6)
      i18n (~> 0.4.1)
      mime-types (~> 1.16)
      treetop (~> 1.4.8)
    mechanize (1.0.0)
      nokogiri (>= 1.2.1)
    mime-types (1.16)
    nokogiri (1.4.3.1)
    pg (0.9.0)
    polyglot (0.3.1)
    rack (1.2.1)
    rack-mount (0.6.13)
      rack (>= 1.0.0)
    rack-test (0.5.6)
      rack (>= 1.0)
    rails (3.0.1)
      actionmailer (= 3.0.1)
      actionpack (= 3.0.1)
      activerecord (= 3.0.1)
      activeresource (= 3.0.1)
      activesupport (= 3.0.1)
      bundler (~> 1.0.0)
      railties (= 3.0.1)
    railties (3.0.1)
      actionpack (= 3.0.1)
      activesupport (= 3.0.1)
      rake (>= 0.8.4)
      thor (~> 0.14.0)
    rake (0.8.7)
    sparklines (0.5.2)
    thor (0.14.4)
    treetop (1.4.8)
      polyglot (>= 0.3.1)
    tzinfo (0.3.23)

PLATFORMS
  ruby

DEPENDENCIES
  calendar_date_select
  googlecharts
  mechanize
  pg
  rails (= 3.0.1)
  sparklines
```

EDIT: (adding Boot.rb details)

```
require 'rubygems'

# Set up gems listed in the Gemfile.
gemfile = File.expand_path('../../Gemfile', __FILE__)
begin
  ENV['BUNDLE_GEMFILE'] = gemfile
  require 'bundler'
  Bundler.setup
rescue Bundler::GemNotFound => e
  STDERR.puts e.message
  STDERR.puts "Try running `bundle install`."
  exit!
end if File.exist?(gemfile)
```

Comment: I've included the file in the original post.

Comment: that looks good to me.  What about the files that script/rails requires like application.rb?  You should have an expand_path to boot, a require for 'rails/all' and call to Bundler.require.  Is all that in there?

Comment: actually.. looks like application.rb gets executed after 'rails/commands'.  boot.rb is called before that require.  What is in that file?

Comment: This shows you the boot process: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/initialization.html    It may be helpful to put some print statements in these files and see whats going on.  I suspect its something with the call to bundler in boot.rb

Comment: oops.. just included the wrong link in that last comment.  I edited it to include the right link to rails guides

Comment: boot.rb looks fine too.  Not sure what is going on here.  Aside from putting some debug statements in boot.rb, and script/rails, the only other thing I would suggest is to create a new blank rails 3 app and see if you can get the server to start there.  If that works, you know for sure its something in your app configuration and not caused by something in your development environment.

Comment: Created a new rails app and it runs without any issues, so the problem must really be somewhere in the specific app configurations. I just followed the railscast tutorial, and before the app was running fine in rails 2.3.5, so not sure where else I should look...

Comment: do you see references to rails 2 & 3 when you run from command line >gem list

Comment: I think thats about all I got.  I guess you could compare the files in /config and /script with the ones in the blank rails app with the ones in the upgrade app.  Aside from that, I might just try the upgrade process again.  I noticed the tutorial said to gem install the --pre version.  If you did that, maybe just try leaving off the --pre flag.  That could be pulling from the master repo and maybe they changed something.  Sorry I couldn't be more help

Comment: Thanks anyway. Let's see if someone can help a bit further on this. Meanwhile will do what you suggested, comparing /config and /script files. And yeah, I left out the -pre version when installing rails.

Comment: It worked. Created an empty environment, copied the app files and a few more ones to the new environment and it is now working. Thank you for the help!

Comment: I actually find that to be an easier way to upgrade.  I converted my first app in a similar fashion to the Railscast, but I did 2 more recently with the copy method,and its fairly easy just to create a new app and copy what you need.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same problem.

I fixed it just deleting the Gemfile.lock file and running from the console

```
bundle install
```

If you have problems with Bundler as well, you can install it again

```
gem install bundler # you may need sudo before.
```

That make it work for me.

Answer (score 0):

`export GEM_HOME=/usr/lib/ruby1.9.1/gems/1.9.1/`

Of course you'll need the appropriate path.